# Swift ios app : sidebar menu, several pages containing table views with pull refresh

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, sidebar

I'm trying to build an iOS app in Swift which looks like the schema below.
I handles a list of channels, and displays a list of items for each channel.

The main view display the list of items for the current channel.
One can go to the next / previous channel by swiping left or right.

One can also display the whole list of channel by opening the sidebar menu, and have a random access to the channel he chooses in the list.

I thought it would be so simple ! But...

I use :

- a table view to display the list of items
- a page view controller to display the channels
- a navigation controller on top to display the name of the app
- SWRevealViewController to have the sidebar menu

Everything is implemented, but I can't get ride of certain bugs nor figure out where those come from :

- the pull & refresh spinner in table view bugs (never stops) from time to time
- page views are rebuilt all the time, they are never cached => I can't initialize a view once for good (and I guess it induces poor performance)
- page views animation behave a weird way : when they appear, they are below the navigation bar (no matter what constraint I set in the storyboard), and return to their right position after a short delay (or sometimes it needs a touch event)

So, I was wondering : isn't their a better way to do all of that ? I feel like I'm just not going the right direction to achieve this. At the beginning, I needed the app to run on iOS 7. It turns out that iOS 8 will be fine.

Thanks for your help !

[image: Schema]